# How to get/access a text field value stored in a C# user Control

Tags: c#, properties, user-controls

Hey so I'm just learning about User Controls, and I have created one. 
I created a User Control Calculator, but now I would like to have access to the text field.
As you know I do not have immediate access to the values stored in my User Control.

I would like to know if there is a way to get this value, or is this simply not possible.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the value of the textfield using one of a Property, Method or by making the TextField a public variable (which I would not recommend).

I would prefer the following.

```
public MyControl : Control {
    public string Result { get { return _txtField.Text; }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an accessor like this

```
public MyUC : WebControl
{
   public TextBox TxtINeedToAccess
   {
     get{return this.txtINeedToAccess;} 
   }
}
```

And in your page:

```
string txtValue = MyUC1.TxtINeedToAccess.Text;
```